# Opposite of any() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable

The Python built-in function `any(iterable)` can help to quickly check if any `bool(element)` is `True` in a iterable type.

```
>>> l = [None, False, 0]
>>> any(l)
False
>>> l = [None, 1, 0]
>>> any(l)
True
```

But is there an elegant way or function in Python that could achieve the opposite effect of `any(iterable)`? That is, if any `bool(element) is False` then return `True`, like the following example:

```
>>> l = [True, False, True]
>>> any_false(l)
>>> True
```

Comment: Your question was correctly answered already by jack Aidley. You may want to check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws for the theory behind it.

Comment: Both JackAidley's and deceze's answer can be helpful depending on your problem. Note that "any element is falsy" isn't the same as "no element is truthy" - they have different answers for the empty array.

Comment: "*notice that `all` returns `True` on empty iterable*" - [of course it does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). Did you expect otherwise?

Comment: @Bergi Nope, I just want to notice some flash people this interesting feature. Anything wrong with my word?

Comment: @EkeymeMo: Dunno, sounded like a warning, as like for something to avoid. Or maybe it's just me.

Comment: I suggested on the Python mailing list a couple of years back introducing `none(...)` for that very purpose, but the suggestion was dismissed, mostly due to its resemblance to `None`.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

There is also the `all` function which does the opposite of what you want, it returns `True` if all are `True` and `False` if any are `False`. Therefore you can just do:

```
not all(l)
```

Comment: Not sure what OP wants if iterable is empty but it's worth noting, `all` returns True on empty iterable.

Comment: @Lafexlos Good point, it's always worth considering the end points. I would guess that `False` for `[]` is the correct answer; which this code give but the OP would have to specify.

Comment: For `all(...)` you can always add `True` to the argument list without changing the output. `True` is a "neutral element" (just like 0 for addition, 1 for multiplication are neutral elements). That's why empty `all()` returns `True`. For `any()` the neutral element is `False`.

Comment: @Fermiparadox: Doing some quick timings this is much faster than the `any` approach as you'd expect since it's all built-in. Deceze's approach is more generally applicable, however.

Comment: +1 A little knowledge of mathematical logic can save a lot of time in the long run: `∃x: ¬x` is equivalent to `¬(∀x: x)`.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification#Negation)

Comment: @Lafexlos, yes, `all` returns True on an empty set because that's how the underlying math works.

Comment: This doesn't short circuit though, if that is the desired behavior.

Comment: @ShaneHsu: Short circuiting may not be faster than native C code of `all`

Comment: @ShaneHsu: What do you mean by "doesn't short circuit"? The `all` call terminates on the first `False` found and is thus much faster for a call with `False` at the start and slower for all `True` - I would describe that as short circuiting.

Answer (score 54):

Write a generator expression which tests your custom condition. You're not bound to only the default *truthiness* test:

```
any(not i for i in l)
```

Comment: Yeah, might be `any(bool(i) == False for i in l)` is better. Right? `None == False` is `False`, but I don't want that. `bool(None) == False` is `True`

Comment: In that case `not i for i in l` would probably be best.

Comment: @EkeymeMo Avoid using `==` to compare against booleans. Just use the bare value eg. `if value: ...`. However, if you absolutely must check if an object is a boolean rather than a truthful value, use `is`. Otherwise you can get unexpected results -- eg. `1 == True` is true, but `2 == True` is false.

Comment: This is significantly slower than `not all(l)`

Comment: @dawg I'm surprised, because this allows short-circuiting, so it can return as soon as a `false` element is found.

Comment: @Barmar: that was my instinct as well, but the timing code is in my post. I suppose that C native code of `all` beats short circuiting of `any` in this case.

Comment: @Barmar `all` will short-circuit as well as soon as it encounters `False`; I assume the hardcoded C style of checking for `False` is simple faster than a Python `not i` in a generator…

Answer (score 16):

Well, the implementation of `any` is [*equivalent*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

So, just switch the condition from `if element` to `if not element`:

```
def reverse_any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return True
    return False
```

Yes, *of course* this doesn't leverage the speed of the built-ins `any` or `all` like the other answers do, but it's a nice readable alternative.

Comment: @JackAidley *Of course it is*, I never made any assertions otherwise. I just added an alternative. Remember, `any` and `all` are generally mystifying to new users, looking at their rough implementation generally helps.

Answer (score 11):

You can do:

```
>>> l = [True, False, True]
>>> False in map(bool, l)
True
```

Recall that `map` in Python 3 is a generator. For Python 2, you probably want to use `imap`

---

Mea Culpa: After timing these, the method I offered is hands down **the slowest**

The fastest is `not all(l)` or `not next(filterfalse(bool, it), True)` which is just a silly itertools variant. Use Jack Aidleys [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38869246/298607).

Timing code:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def af1(it):
    return not all(it)

def af2(it):
    return any(not i for i in it)   

def af3(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return True
    return False    

def af4(it):
    return False in map(bool, it)   

def af5(it):
    return not next(filterfalse(bool, it), True)    

if __name__=='__main__':
    import timeit   
    for i, l in enumerate([[True]*1000+[False]+[True]*999, # False in the middle
                           [False]*2000, # all False
                            [True]*2000], # all True
                            start=1): 
        print("case:", i)
        for f in (af1, af2, af3, af4, af5):
            print("   ",f.__name__, timeit.timeit("f(l)", setup="from __main__ import f, l", number=100000), f(l) )
```

Results:

```
case: 1
    af1 0.45357259700540453 True
    af2 4.538436588976765 True
    af3 1.2491040650056675 True
    af4 8.935278153978288 True
    af5 0.4685744970047381 True
case: 2
    af1 0.016299808979965746 True
    af2 0.04787631600629538 True
    af3 0.015038023004308343 True
    af4 0.03326922300038859 True
    af5 0.029870904982089996 True
case: 3
    af1 0.8545824179891497 False
    af2 8.786235476000002 False
    af3 2.448748088994762 False
    af4 17.90895140200155 False
    af5 0.9152941330103204 False
```